# python library's setup.py and dependency on distro-level python code

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi, cherokee

So I am packaging some code that I have as a proper "pypi-compliant" python package.

The problem is, my python library depends on some python classes in a distro-level only library - specifically cherokee.

Installed via

```
 aptitude install cherokee
```

or

```
pacman -S cherokee
```

or

```
emerge cherokee
```

depending on which distro you use of course.

In my installed cherokee library, I can locate

```
[root@li280-195 ~]# find / -name "Config.py"
/usr/share/cherokee/admin/CTK/CTK/Config.py
```

So the question is, how should I indicate in my python library's `setup.py`, that I depend on `Config.py` ?

Comment: You probably would have to build a distro package (.deb) file for it. I don't think setuptools supports that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTK isn't available as a standalone package.